# Install docker desktop out of system driver

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I installed `docker desktop` a bit, and soon it eat up my space on system drive - I looked a around but didn't find a way to change:

1. Docker Desktop installation path to another drive, like D:\
2. Downloaded images to another driver, like D:\

Is `Docker Desktop` actually support that？ How could I achieve that?

Comment: Apparently there is only method so far: 1] Uninstall Docker for Desktop → 2] Create a junction link between the default installation directory and your directory of choice → 3] Install Docker → more at https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-installation-directory/32773/9

Somebody should really start working on that feature request https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/94

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin, can't believe after 1+ year this is still not yet supported.....